# RestEasy: How to validate ClientResponse body?

Tags: java, rest, testing, resteasy

I have a `REST` endpoint as

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getVariables(@QueryParam("_activeonly") @DefaultValue("no") @Nonnull final Active active) {
    switch(active){
        case yes:
        return Response.ok(VariablePresentation.getPresentationVariables(variableManager.getActiveVariables())).build();
        case no:
        return Response.ok(VariablePresentation.getPresentationVariables(variableManager.getVariables())).build();
    }
    throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Which returns `JSON` of `List` of `VariablePresentation`. The `VariablePresentaion` looks like

```
@XmlRootElement
public class VariablePresentation {

    private final UUID id;
    private final String name;
    private final VariableType type;

    public VariablePresentation(@Nonnull final Variable variable) {
        id = variable.getId();
        name = variable.getName();
        type = variable.getType();
                }

    public String getId() {
        return id.toString();
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public VariableType getType() {
        return type;
    }
```

annotated with `JAXB`'s `XmlRoot` to return `JSON`.
My integration test is as following

```
@Test
public void testGetAllVariablesWithoutQueryParamPass() throws Exception {
    final ClientRequest clientCreateRequest = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:9090/variables");
    final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParameters = clientCreateRequest.getFormParameters();
    final String name = "testGetAllVariablesWithoutQueryParamPass";
    formParameters.putSingle("name", name);
    formParameters.putSingle("type", "String");
    formParameters.putSingle("units", "units");
    formParameters.putSingle("description", "description");
    formParameters.putSingle("core", "true");
    final ClientResponse<String> clientCreateResponse = clientCreateRequest.post(String.class);
    assertEquals(201, clientCreateResponse.getStatus());
}
```

I want to test the request body which returns the `List<VariablePresentation>` as String. How can I convert the response body (String) as `VariablePresentation` Object?

**Update**

After adding the following

```
        final GenericType<List<VariablePresentation>> typeToken = new GenericType<List<VariablePresentation>>() {
        };
        final ClientResponse<List<VariablePresentation>> clientCreateResponse = clientCreateRequest.post(typeToken);
        assertEquals(201, clientCreateResponse.getStatus());
        final List<VariablePresentation> variables = clientCreateResponse.getEntity();
        assertNotNull(variables);
        assertEquals(1, variables.size());
```

Its fails with different Error

```
testGetAllVariablesWithoutQueryParamPass(com.myorg.project.market.integration.TestVariable): Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type java.util.List<com.myorg.project.service.presentation.VariablePresentation>
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found is to use ClientResponse with [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/)

A simple example could be

```
  @Test
    public void testGetAllVariablesWithoutQueryParamNoPass() throws Exception {
        final ClientRequest clientCreateRequest_var0 = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:9090/variables?_activeonly=no");
        final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParameters = clientCreateRequest_var0.getFormParameters();
        final String name0 = "testGetAllVariablesWithoutQueryParamNoPass_0";
        formParameters.putSingle("name", name0);
        formParameters.putSingle("type", "String");
        formParameters.putSingle("units", "units");
        formParameters.putSingle("description", "description");
        formParameters.putSingle("core", "true");

        final ClientResponse<String> clientCreateResponse_var0 = clientCreateRequest_var0.post(String.class);
        assertEquals(201, clientCreateResponse_var0.getStatus());

        final ClientRequest clientCreateRequest_var1 = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:9090/variables");
        final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParameters1 = clientCreateRequest_var1.getFormParameters();
        final String name1 = "testGetAllVariablesWithoutQueryParamNoPass_1";
        formParameters1.putSingle("name", name1);
        formParameters1.putSingle("type", "String");
        formParameters1.putSingle("units", "units");
        formParameters1.putSingle("description", "description");
        formParameters1.putSingle("core", "true");

        final ClientResponse<String> clientCreateResponse_var1 = clientCreateRequest_var1.post(String.class);
        assertEquals(201, clientCreateResponse_var1.getStatus());

        final ClientRequest clientCreateRequest2 = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:9090/variables");
        final ClientResponse<String> clientCreateResponse2 = clientCreateRequest2.get(String.class);

        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        final Type variableType = new TypeToken<List<VariablePresentation>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<VariablePresentation> variables = gson.fromJson(clientCreateResponse2.getEntity(), variableType);
        assertNotNull(variables);

        assertEquals(2, variables.size());

        // clean test data
        removeTestDataVariableObject(name0);
        removeTestDataVariableObject(name1);
    }
```